# Xamarin iOS Local Notifications not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

I've walked through the Xamarin walkthrough on iOS local notifications:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/local_notifications_in_ios_walkthrough/

And I just can't get it to work. It builds fine, but the `ReceivedLocalNotification` method on `AppDelegate` never fires. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your app foreground or background when the notification fires? ReceivedLocalNotification method will just fire if your app is foreground.

Comment: @FormigaNinja, then which method to use when app is in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on iOS 8 you'll also need to register your app to receive notifications, as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Add the following code to the `FinishedLaunching` method of your `AppDelegate` class:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0)) {
    UIUserNotificationType notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | 
                UIUserNotificationType.Badge | 
                UIUserNotificationType.Sound;

    var userNoticationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(notificationTypes, new NSSet(new string[] {}));

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (userNoticationSettings);
}
```

Comment: Hi FormigaNinja. I've answered my own question here so am I correct in thinking that I can't mark it as accepted for another 2 days?

Comment: As an extension to this that if you're running a device NOT in ios8, the code you added will throw an error, so wrap the code inside a standard check for IOS version.